# in C#, is it possible to move files based on date created? If so, what class/module should I use?

Tags: c#

I haven't seen it under system.io, but can I move or sort files (any files) based on each file's create date? So for example, I have Folder A with hundreds of files....want to move some of them to Folder B (and possibly zip/compress them)..lets say those that are older than 60 days.

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use File.GetCreationTime to sort/move based on that.

Also FileInfo has a CreationTime property you can use.